# How to get correct path to file in class libary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have working code for this but I want to optomize it.

I have a MVC Web api and I have tried to build this app with a new structure. I have the project and I have two other projects that are class libraries. In one of these class libraries I have a folder "files" that contains a file that I want to retrive.

Structure:

[image]

I have this code:

```
            char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            string startupPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
            string[] pathItems = startupPath.Split(separator);
            string projectPath = string.Join(separator.ToString(),
                pathItems.Take(pathItems.Length - 1)) + ".Handler";
            string path = Path.Combine(projectPath, "WebRequestHandlers\\Files" + separator + "Domains.ini");
```

This Code works.

I dont like the fact that I have to hardcode

> ".Handler"

to the project path to make this work. My question is, how can I access the class libary from AppDomain, example:

> Appdomain.CurrentDomain.SomeMethodToLibary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just me or what you are doing will not work once you publish your application because you are getting the file path as per your development folder hierarchy ?

What you should do is change the "Build Action" and "Copy To Output Directory" like so:
[image: Properties]

With those options the file gets copied to the "bin" directory of your main solution (or a sub folder of bin matching where the file is. You should check).
The file will be always in the same place and it will get published.

So now the path to your file would be something like this:

```
string startupPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
string path = Path.Combine(startupPath, "WebRequestHandlers", "Files", "Domains.ini");
```

Comment: The code has worked on other projects. The diffirence is the hardcoded ".handler" to the path. Thanks for pointing this out, If i get problems when i publish ill be sure to check this

Comment: Well by using the file copied to the output directory you no longer have to hardcode _.handler_ and it will work once deployed. You better do it the right way from the start.